# How to pipe multiple commands into a single command in the shell? (sh, bash, ...)

Tags: bash, shell, process, pipe, subshell

How can I pipe the stdout of multiple commands to a single command?

Example 1: combine and sort the output of all three echo commands:

```
echo zzz; echo aaa; echo kkk
```

desired output:

```
aaa
kkk
zzz
```

Example 2: rewrite the following so that all the commands are in a single command-line using pipes, without redirects to a temp file:

```
setopt > /tmp/foo; unsetopt >> /tmp/foo; set >> /tmp/foo; sort /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use parentheses ()'s to combine the commands into a single process, which will concatenate the stdout of each of them.

Example 1 (note that `$` is the shell prompt):

```
$ (echo zzz; echo aaa; echo kkk) | sort
aaa
kkk
zzz
```

Example 2:

```
$ (setopt; unsetopt; set) | sort
```

Comment: @glenn: that doesn't matter (tested in bash 3.2.48), since the pipeline forces it into a subshell anyway.

Comment: @KennyEvitt Check the [pipeline section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines): "Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell...". Actually, this can be changed with [`shopt -s lastpipe`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), which runs the *last* section of a pipeline in the current shell. But in this case it's the first section we're concerned with, so it'd still run in a subshell.

Comment: @KennyEvitt It seems to coalesce them into a single level of subshell (at least under bash, test w/ versions 2.05b.0, 3.2.57, and 4.2.10; other shells may differ). But when I use `{ ( echo zzz; echo aaa; echo kkk ) } | sort` I do get the extra subshell.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `{}` for this and eliminate the need for a sub-shell as in `(list)`, like so:

```
{ echo zzz; echo aaa; echo kkk; } | sort
```

We do need a whitespace character after `{` and before `}`.  We also need the last `;` when the sequence is written on a single line.

We could also write it on multiple lines without the need for any `;`:

Example 1:

```
{
  echo zzz
  echo aaa
  echo kkk
} | sort
```

Example 2:

```
{
  setopt
  unsetopt
  set
} | sort
```

Answer (score 3):

In Windows it would be as follow: `(echo zzz & echo aaa & echo kkk) | sort`

Or if it is inside a batch file it can be mono line (like sample) as well as multiline:

```
(
 echo zzz
 echo aaa
 echo kkk
) | sort
```

Note: The original post does not mention it is only for Linux, so I added the solution for Windows command line... it is very useful when working with VHD/VHDX with diskpart inside scripts (`echo diskpart_command`) instead of the echo on the same, but let there the `echo`, there is also another way without echos and with `>` redirector, but it is very prone to errors and much more complex to write (why use a complicated prone to errors way if exists a simple way that allways work well)... also remember `%d%` gives you the actual path (very useful for not hardcoding the path of VHD/VHDX files).