# piping and executing multiple arguments in BASH

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, pipe

I would like to run the following command and pipe stout of both to textedit:

pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions | open -f -a TextEdit

This doesn't work, it only executes the latter.

Also, anyway to execute multiple arguments for the same command like:

pmset -g { echo, assertions}

I'm sure this will get voted down for being a basic question. Thanks in advance to any who reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917708/pipe-multiple-commands-to-a-single-command

Comment: Just use the > operator to redirect your output on a file...and THEN open the file with TextEdit.

Comment: @elbuild Intermediate file not necessary. Just pipe `stdin` to `open -f` and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions) | open -f -a TextEdit

Comment: In fact, you can remove `-a TextEdit` all together. `open -f` opens TextEdit with the contents of `stdin`

Answer (score 1):

> Also, anyway to execute multiple arguments for the same command like:
>
> pmset -g { echo, assertions}

That is entirely up to the program, in this case `pmset`. Some programs allow you to use a switch multiple times, as in `pmset -g echo -g assertions`

However, that doesn't seem to be the case with [pmset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for this reply to my second question. I don't have enough reputation to "vote up," but will when I gain it.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can use curly bracket

```
{ pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions; } | open -f -a TextEdit
```

`(pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions)` is executing the commands in a subshell
`{ pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions; }` is executing the commands in current shell

Comment: You must have a space between the braces `{ <-space-> }`, otherwise it will fail.