# Why are spaces required before a curly brace in a function definition?

Tags: bash, function, shell, syntax

I'm trying to create a bash script that converts a bunch of pdfs into text in order to extract some information but the shell gives me this error:

```
./AutoBib.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `pdftotext'
./AutoBib.sh: line 8: `    pdftotext $1 temp.txt'
```

Here there is an example of my function:

```
function doi{

    pdftotext $1 temp.txt
    cat temp.txt | grep doi: | cut -d: -f 2 | head -n 1 >> dois.txt
    rm -rf temp.txt
}
doi $PDF
```

Where the variable `PDF` is taken in input. Before adding the function it worked, I used to write in my script:

```
pdftotext $PDF tempo.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Bash [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping):

> The braces are reserved words, so they must be separated from the list
>   by blanks or other shell metacharacters.

`function ...` is an [outdated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete) syntax for defining Bash functions.  Use this instead:

```
doi() {
   ...
}
```

Since `()` are meta characters, you don't need a space in this case (though spaces make your code prettier):

```
doi(){
  ...
}
```

Extending this a little, remember that we need a whitespace (space, tab, or newline) after `{` and before `}' in command [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42258145/6862601), like this:

```
{ command1; command2; ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a space after the name of your function and before the `{`:

```
function doi {
            ^
```

Comment: Right. (Well, strictly speaking, you don't. Bash lets you define a function named `doi{` -- but then you'd need a `{` token after the function name.) The issue is that `doi{` is a single token, not an identifier `doi` followed by a `{` token.