# How to execute bash command with multiple steps using `exec`

Tags: php, bash, exec

I have multistep command, that asks for several questions in the process. I need to execute it from within the code.

```
php command.php
> What is your name?
User Smith
> What is your age?
25
> You are old enough!
```

But when I call it with `exec` it is just stuck.

What I expect, is something like:

```
<?php

$result = exec('php command.php')->next('User Smith')->next('25');

if ($result->response === 'You are old enough!') echo "Yahoo";
else  echo "Oh no!";
```

Answer (score 1):

We can chain commands using the pipe operator. We can do it like that:

`exec('(echo 'User Smith' & echo '25') | php command.php')`

The direction is from right to left.

[Pipe multiple commands into a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917708/pipe-multiple-commands-into-a-single-command)